# MySQL sorting/grouping inside JOIN

Tags: sql, join, correlated-subquery

hi have the following schema

```
-- Accounts ----
[id]    name
----------------
20    BigCompany
25    SomePerson


-- Followers -------
[id   follower_id]
--------------------
20    25


-- Daily Metrics --------------------------------
[id    date ]       follower_count   media_count
-------------------------------------------------
25    2015-10-07    350              24
25    2015-10-13    500              27
25    2015-10-12    480              26
```

I would like a list of all followers of a particular account, returning their most up to date `follower_count`. I've tried JOINs, correlated subqueries etc but none are working for me.

Expected result for followers of `BigCompany`:

```
id    username    follower_count   media_count  'last_checked'
---------------------------------------------------------------
25    SomePerson  500              27            2015-10-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some `JOIN`'s, use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude older metrics:

```
select a1.id, a1.name, dm.follower_count, dm.media_count, dm.date as "last_checked"
from Accounts a1
  join Followers f on f.follower_id = a1.id
  join Accounts a2 on f.id = a2.id
  join DailyMetrics dm on dm.id = a1.id
where a2.name = 'BigCompany'
  and not exists (select 1 from DailyMetrics
                  where id = dm.id
                    and date > dm.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.id,
  a.name           AS username,
  d.media_count,
  d.date           AS last_checked
FROM Accounts AS a
INNER JOIN Followers    AS f ON a.id = f.follower_id
INNER JOIN DailyMetrics AS d ON d.id = f.follower_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
  FROM DailyMetrics 
  GROUP BY id
) AS dm ON d.date = dm.maxdate
WHERE f.id = 999 ;
```

The subquery:

```
  SELECT id, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
  FROM DailyMetrics 
  GROUP BY id
```

Will get the most recent date for each `id`, then `JOIN`ing it with the table `DailyMetrics` will eliminate all the rows except the one with the most recent date.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80def/6)

This will give you:

```
| id |       name | media_count |                      date |
|----|------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| 25 | SomePerson |          27 | October, 13 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: HI should have been clearer I need to specifiy which account I'm looking for the followers from, eg WHERE followers.id = 999

Comment: @AlasdairC - No problem, you can add it to the end of the query, see my updated query.

Comment: this returns 900K rows, lots of duplicate rows

Comment: @AlasdairC - use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT.

Comment: @AlasdairC - This query should work find, you can try it and test it from here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80def/6

Comment: Thank you for all the effort, but I was still getting duplicate rows, although less than 900K this time. The other answer worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Id_max as
(Select id, max(date) As MaxDate
  From DailyMetrics 
  Group By id)
Select
  a.id,
  a.name           As username,
  d.follower_count As MediaCount,
  d.date           As last_checked
From Accounts As a
 join Followers    As f ON a.id = f.follower_id
join DailyMetrics As d ON d.id = f.follower_id
join id_max on id_max.id=a.id and MaxDate=date
Where f.id = "WhatYouWant"
```

Comment: From the title: **MySQL sorting/grouping inside JOIN**